# Can I Host A Url in another Country and get rank well?

Tags: domain, domain-registration

Hello I live in the US, but i want to host a few sites in different countries.. ? I would like to know if i can...

1) Register a domain with a uk, au, extension

2) Host the domain in the same country

3)Set the geographic location for the site in Google Webmaster Tools...

4) Will this hurt my SEO rankings?

4) Lastly will it be smart for me to get a vpn or will google not care because i have done all the three above, it doesnt seem blackhat to me...

Thanks soo much for any  feedback

Answer (score 1):

Just do it. Google will not care. Ther are dozens of good reasons to do that for larger companies (like keeping all hosting centarl in one location).